# Create struct in method and call its components in (form or timer)

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, struct

I've been following tutorial once again. Making a flappy bird clone.

According to tutorial i need to create a struct:

```
    struct Bird
    {
        public float velocityY;
        public float angle;

        public RectangleF bird;

        public Image image;
    }
```

And then i need to create a method, that suppose to create a instance of that struct:

```
    private void CreateBird()
    {
        Bird mBird;

        mBird.image = imageBird;
        mBird.velocityY = 0;
        mBird.bird = new RectangleF(Width / 2 - birdWidth, Height / 2, birdWidth, birdHeight);
        mBird.angle = 0;

    }
```

And here's the kicker.. Nowhere in tutorial its mentioned where you need to put this method.

And for example (obvious but still) I get an error on "mBird.image" when try to do smth like this:

```
  private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(Color.DeepSkyBlue);

        g.DrawImage(mBird.image, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
```

Sow how can you create something like that?

Comment: Sounds like a crappy tutorial. I don't know what you expect us to do about that though.

Comment: *Where* you declare something defines its `Scope`.  Your `mBird` is declared in that void method so that is the only place it exists.  Declare it at the form level.... and `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  Do your painting in the paint event and use the `Graphics` made available to your there.

Comment: This is Winforms.  I hoped there is a way to this kind of code at all.. And may be ill be able to figure something out from that point.

Comment: declare your `mBird` object at the class level ([the `m` stands for "member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018189/what-does-m-variable-prefix-mean), after all), so you can access it from both `CreateBird` and `Timer1_Tick`

Comment: This is not an appropriate situation to use a `struct`.  Given that the tutorial is trying to get you to do things like this, you should really stop using it and find a better tutorial to use.