# Paramater or variable name?

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

Why everyone write variable starts with m? Adapter mApapter? But Android studio suggest Adapter adapter .
what is the good coding practice?which one is very clear to read.
what is use the universal name convention? I saw something like that on php.Adapter pAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

'm' means member of the class. So, if you don't use IDE to highlight your members, then you will understand that it is a member by it's name.

Somtimes people use other prefixes if you discover some variables starting with 'i' or 's' it could also be a variant of the [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)

For more info see [Why do variable names often start with the letter 'm'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237469/why-do-variable-names-often-start-with-the-letter-m)

In Android Coding Style Field Naming Conventions are

- Non-public, non-static field names start with m.
- Static field names start with s.
- Other fields start with a lower case letter.
- Public static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

For more info see [Android Follow Field Naming Conventions](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at the Android code-style page you can see that:

- Non-public, non-static field names start with m
- Static field names start with s.
- Other fields start with a lower case letter.
- Public static final fields (constants) are
  ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Those are naming conventions for the AOSP project, and as many conventions, are a matter of religion more than reason. Those were not recommended neither in the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) nor in [Google´s Java Style Conventions](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5-naming).

In practice each organization or project has it own conventions.

I'd name it "adapter" for instance.