# Android programming m before objects

Tags: java, android, object

I am new in Android programming, and I saw there is a "m" before objects, like:

mCursor

mAdpter

mView

---

So what is this "m"? Should I use it in my code?

Sorry for this poor question...

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092098/why-most-of-android-tutorials-variables-start-with-m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow Field Naming Conventions

1. Non-public, non-static field names start with m.
2. Static field names start with s.
3. Other fields start with a lower case letter.
4. Public static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

You can see the document on those rules [here](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions).

Comment: In 9 minutes, I tried already.

Comment: LOL, enjoy the weekend!

Comment: And what about local variables (inside methods), prameters of methods, and arrays or lists?

Comment: My opinion, those fall under point 3.

Comment: I hate those ugly m's!