# Why does this Android developer doc name some of its variables with TWO m's

Tags: android, naming-conventions

I understand the reasoning behind [one m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092098/why-most-of-android-tutorials-variables-start-with-m) as a non-static, private variable. But what about when there are two m's as seen [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)?

[image]

Comment: Sub-class private non-static?

Comment: Makes sense to me. If you make an answer id mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for sure, but I suspect it is meant to signify a sub-class private non-static variable.