# What does mListener stand for？Why not use listener directly?

Tags: android

I am writing android now, and this "mListener" name appears in Google's API guide of fragment.
Why not just use listener? What is the significance of the m?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092098/why-do-most-variables-in-android-tutorial-start-with-m

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a technical problem but a problem with understanding the basics of programming in general.

Comment: Well, I believe style is certainly important to your technical engineering effort.

Answer (score 1):

The `mListener` is the name of the variable declared in a class. It is named with [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) naming convention.

The people who wrote AOSP followed this standard and it eventually caught up with third party app developers. It is entirely up to you to decide whether you want to follow this convention.